# Algorithm: Find minimum sum of k numbers from n arrays(queues)

Tags: algorithm

Suppose there are n queues of positive numbers. I need to minimum sum of k numbers selected from these queues. Note that these are queues so ordering is important and only first number can be selected from any queue at a time. Once that number is selected and removed from queue we can proceed to the next one in that queue. So sorting is not allowed(order is important).

For example:

Find minimum sum of two numbers

```
2 12 3 4 
8 2 2
10 10
```

In the above example I can either choose 2 from first queue and 8 from second or 8 and 2 both from second. Both choices give sum 10.

Example 2:

Find minimum sum of two numbers

```
4 15 2
8 2 2
10 10
```

In the above example one has to choose 8 and 2 both from second list.

I was first thinking on the line of merge K sorted lists but it won't work. I can only think of one working approach for this. It is to try all the combinations from all the queues. 
Can someone suggest a better way or guide me towards it?

Comment: Is it right that all selected numbers should be different? That is one can't choose 2 two times.

Comment: No, elements can be repeated. So 2 can be chosen two times.

Comment: But you're saying "one has to choose 8 and 2 both from second list." - I see 2 is repeated 3 times in 2nd example. Why it can't be chosen twice giving sum 4?

Comment: @NikolayPolivanov Ordering is important. So one has to choose 8 before choosing 2 from the second queue. Also, we only need to choose two elements such that the sum is lowest.

Comment: @Pukki Why can't we choose both 2's from the first queue then for a sum of 4?

Comment: Ohh sorry. I meant to give a different example. I will edit the question. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Unless the n arrays have some special structure (ie. are sorted), you might as well simplify the problem to one long array.

Comment: @ColonelPanic The n arrays are actually queues as I have mentioned in my description. So, if I merge them into one I will lose the special structure of n different queues. I will change the misleading topic of the question

Comment: @Pukki You can think of n queues as one long queue. Loop over the first queue, then the second...

Comment: @ColonelPanic I am afraid I don't quite get your point. If I append one queue after another and treat it as a single queue I will be forced to choose all the elements from first queue if I want to choose any element from second. Note that if nth element is chosen from any queue then all elements from 0 to n-1 positions must also be chosen. You can't drop any of the chosen elements. In other words you can select starting chunks from N different queues such that when you put together all the chunks its size is K.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let `F(qs, k)` be the minimum sum from choosing k numbers from the queues `qs`. Then:

```
F([], k) = 0 if k == 0, otherwise +infinity.
F([q] + qs, k) = min_i(q[0] + q[1] + ... + q[i-1] + F(qs, k-i) for i in 0...k)
```

That is, if you've no queues left, the min sum is 0, otherwise, you can take `i` numbers from the first queue, and `k-i` from the rest.

This can be solved efficiently using dynamic programming by building a table of (n, k) where n is the number of queues. In Python 2:

```
def F(qs, n, k, cache):
    if k == 0:
        return 0
    if n == 0:
        return 1e12
    if (n, k) not in cache:
        best = 1e12
        s = 0
        for i in xrange(k+1):
            if i > len(qs[len(qs)-n]):
                break
            if i > 0:
                s += qs[len(qs)-n][i-1]
            best = min(best, s + F(qs, n-1, k-i, cache))
        cache[n, k] = best
    return cache[n, k]

egs = [
    (2, [[2, 2, 3, 4], [8, 2, 2], [10, 10]]),
    (2, [[4, 15, 2], [8, 2, 2], [10, 10]]),
    (3, [[100, 100, 100], [101, 101, 2]])
]

for k, qs in egs:
    print k, qs
    print F(qs, len(qs), k, dict())
    print
```

Prints

```
2 [[2, 2, 3, 4], [8, 2, 2], [10, 10]]
4

2 [[4, 15, 2], [8, 2, 2], [10, 10]]
10

3 [[100, 100, 100], [101, 101, 2]]
204
```

Comment: Seems correct and brilliant. I will just check it a little and then accept.

Comment: It seems so simple after you know the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Isn't it the same as trying all combinations, with an elegant optimization of dynamic programming?

Comment: What is the complexity? Is it factorial?

Comment: @2501 It's not factorial due to `cache` -- O(n k^2) assuming constant-time hashing.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat I used a dict to make the code simpler, but (as I'm sure you know) the cache can be replaced by an n-by-k table to remove any questions about the cost of hashing.

Comment: Can you explain why the solution to the second example isn't 2+2 = 4?

Comment: @ColonelPanic you can only take numbers from the start of the lists.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, the table would contain all the sub-sums of the individual arrays? So in the table, n is index of one of the queues and k is index of one of the sub-sums of only that queue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First try solving a simpler problem: How to find the smallest k elements from an array length m?

Initialise a max-heap size k from the first k elements of the array (yes max-heap rather than min-heap). Loop over the rest of the array. At each step, compare the current element with the root of the heap (this is the kth smallest element seen so far). If the current element is smaller, remove the heap root and insert the current element, being careful to maintain the heap-invariant.

When done, the heap contains the smallest k elements from the array. The algorithm has time complexity O(m log k) and space complexity O(k)

---

Implementation in Python. Python has only a [min-heap module](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/heapq.html), so emulate a max-heap by taking the negative of everything.

```
import heapq # min-heap operations 

def sum_smallest_k(queues, k):
    """Sum the smallest k elements across queues"""
    heap = [] # maintain a max-heap size k

    for queue in queues:
        for x in queue:
            if len(heap) < k:
                heapq.heappush(heap, -1 * x)
            else:
                heapq.heappushpop(heap, -1 * x)

    return -1 * sum(heap)
```

Your examples

```
>>> sum_smallest_k([[2, 12, 3, 4], [8, 2, 2], [10, 10]], 2)
4
>>> sum_smallest_k([[4, 15, 2], [8, 2, 2], [10, 10]], 2)
4
```

Comment: How is this applicable to my question? Are you suggesting some tweak in your algorithm that would then fit my problem? Otherwise I don't see it working.

Comment: You have n arrays. Pretend you just have one long array.

Comment: @Pukki If it helps, here's a Python implementation

Comment: This does not solve the problem of taking _exactly_ `k` elements from the `n` queues. Instead, it drains a queue (or the concatenation of `n` queues).

Comment: In the second example, it is choosing both 2s from the second array  and gives result 4. If I choose 2 at index 1 and 2 at index 2 then I must choose 8 at index 0. So total will be 8 + 2 + 2 = 12. When actually the result should be 8 + 2 = 10 both from second array. It is giving wrong answer in the first example also. I think you are missing the point that the question tries to make. These are queues so if you deque any element then it is a part of your collection.

Comment: Actually this is the best answer. Much efficient than @paul-hankin 's . This requires only O(k) space (compared to O(nk) space). Also run time is O(mlogk) worst case. Whereas runtime for the other algorithm is O(mk). (m is the total number of elements across all queues).